# Calculate the mutual information between two vectors in Matlab (no distribution, no integers)

Tags: matlab, statistics, physics

i'm trying to calculate the mutual information (MI) between two vectors X and Y filled with measurement-values of a simulation. Because the numbers aren't in the same range my first idea was to normalize them to positive numbers between 0 and 1. The next step would be to divide this range in segments (with a number of bins B) and use the function histcounts (histcounts2 for the joint probability) to get the number of measurment-values in each of these segments. Then I calculate the MI (formula is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information). Because there might be the case that no values are in a segment and the probability is therefore 0, I considered special cases in the lower if-statement.
Now the problem: All values I get for the MI are less than 0, but they have to be equal to or greater than 0. Where is my mistake?

```
clear, clc, close all

%get the data:
Data = uiimport('SMatrices6.mat');
X = real(Data.data(:,1,1));
Y = real(Data.data(:,2,1));

%normalize the values between 0 and 1:
mx = min(X);
my = min(Y);
X = X + abs(mx);
Y = Y + abs(my);
MX = max(X);
MY = max(Y);
X = X./MX;
Y = Y./MY;

%calculate the MI for different numbers of bins:
for B = 20:300
    [NXY,EXXY,EXYY] = histcounts2(X,Y,B);
    [NX,EX] = histcounts(X,B);
    [NY,EY] = histcounts(Y,B);

    histogram2(X,Y,B)

    I = 0;

    for ii = 1:length(NX)
        for jj = 1:length(NY)
            px = NX(ii)/length(X);
            py = NY(jj)/length(Y);
            pxy = NXY(ii,jj)/(length(X) * length(Y));
            %special cases:
            if (pxy == 0 || px == 0 || py == 0)
                p = 0;
            else
                p = pxy * log2(pxy/(px * py));
            end
            I = I + p;
        end
    end
    disp(I)
end
```

I tried to compute the MI with histcounts, expected the value to be greater than or equal to zero, but it was actually less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's necessary to rescale the input data, but if you want to you can save a few lines using `X = normalize(X,"range",[0 1]);`

Secondly, the calculations for `px`, `py` and `pxy` are slightly incorrect. The denominator should be the number of observations, rather than the number of bins.

Each of `px`, `py` and `pxy` should sum to one because they are discrete probability density functions that you are deriving from your sample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your method to rescale the data is much easier. I also found a solution in adding (..., 'Normalization', 'probability') to the histcounts function. Now it works (the sum of px, py and pxy are 1)!

Comment: Even better, nice find with the Normalization parameter!